# Regex to replace a prefix string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace a substring with a itself followed by a dot, when it is start of a longer sequence (i.e. it is a prefix). For example given the string:

```
"'abc' 'xyzabcdef' 'abcdef'"
```

I want to transform the prefix `abc` into `abc.`, to give:

```
"'abc' 'xyzabcdef' 'abc.def'"
```

Note that the standalone string of `abc` is not transformed.

I have tried this code:

```
var input = @"'abc' 'xyzabcdef' 'abcdef'";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(abc)\w+", @"$1.");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

which gives:

```
'abc' 'xyzabcdef' 'abc.'
```

Note in the third output, the trailing `def` is also substituted. I expected the substitution of `$1` would have been associated with just the group `(abc)`, but it clearly matches the entire pattern. I'm looking for the correct formulation of the `Regex.Replace()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing on the regex pattern `(?<=')abc(?=\w)`.  This pattern says to match:

```regex
(?<=')  assert that single quote precedes
abc     match and consume abc
(?=\w)  assert that at least one word character follows
```

```cs
var input = @"'abc' 'xyzabcdef' 'abcdef'";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=')abc(?=\w)", @"abc.");
Console.WriteLine(result);  // 'abc' 'xyzabcdef' 'abc.def'
```